# How To Set Many Elements Visible Property at one time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have 5 Elements => Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5.

General Way to set their **Visible** Property is:

```
 Element1.Visible = false;
 Element2.Visible = false;
 Element3.Visible = false;
 Element4.Visible = false;
 Element5.Visible = false;
```

Or Another Way is

```
 Element1.Visible = Element2.Visible = Element3.Visible = Element4.Visible = Element5.Visible = false;
```

**Now My Question is:**

Is It possible to set all elements property Visible at same time without writing Visible against every element name. In Simple Word only need to write Visible one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find controls and set its visisble property

Here is the example code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideRadioButtonLists(Page.Controls);
}

private void HideRadioButtonLists(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (WebControl control in controls.OfType<WebControl>())
    {
        if (control is RadioButtonList)
            control.Visible = false;
        else if (control.HasControls())
            HideRadioButtonLists(control.Controls);
    }
}
```

See if it helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to use my second way and did not need to write Visible against each element to set their property. i.e. writing minimum code

Comment: nope, you need to set value explicitly.
You need to write some lines of code.